# Nagios NRPE: unable to read output for custom check

Tags: ubuntu, nagios

I have written a custom ruby script to check disk usage for each volume on an ubuntu server. The servers are controlled by puppet and the nagios system has been running for years and contains a number of other custom checks. When I run my new script script on the nagios server it returns the expected output but when I run it for another server it returns NRPE:unable to read output. Running a standard plugin works on any server.

I have only loaded the file into /usr/lib/nagios/plugins and included a command in nrpe.cfg to enable me to run it from the command line in a terminal.

Do I need to set a host name (or host group) and service for my custom check for the client server to make it work on that server, even from the command line?

Here is the command in nrpe.cfg

```
command[check_disk_usage]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_disk_usage.rb
```

Here are some examples of commands which illustrate the issue.

```
nagios@nagios-server:~$ /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H nagios-server
NRPE v2.15

nagios@nagios-server:~$ /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H client-server
NRPE v2.15

nagios@nagios-server:~$ /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H nagios-server -c check_users
USERS OK - 2 users currently logged in |users=2;5;5;0

nagios@nagios-server:~$ /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H client-server -c check_users
USERS OK - 2 users currently logged in |users=2;5;5;0

nagios@nagios-server:~$ /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H nagios-server -c check_disk_usage
OK - '/backups' 79% of disk space used | '/'=37% '/tmp'=1% '/srv'=62% '/backups'=79%

nagios@nagios-server:~$ /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H client-server -c check_disk_usage
NRPE: Unable to read output
```

Here is my custom check script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def largest_hash_key(hash)
  hash.max_by{|k,v| v}
end

filesystem = %x(df -h)

perfdata = filesystem.split("\n")
                 .grep(/\A\/dev/)
                 .map(&:split)
                 .map{ |e| "'%s'=%s" % [ e[-1], e[-2] ] }
                 .join(" ")

volumes = Hash[perfdata.split(" ").map {|str| str.split("=")}]

volumes = volumes.map{ |k, v| [k, v.to_i] }

full_disk = largest_hash_key(volumes)

pc_full = full_disk[1]

message = "#{perfdata} | #{perfdata}" 

if pc_full > 94
   puts "DISK CRITICAL - #{message}"
   exit 2
elsif pc_full > 89
   puts "DISK WARNING - #{message}"
   exit 1
else
   puts "DISK OK - #{message}"
   exit 0   
end
```

Comment: Can you post the "client-server" "check_disk_usage" configuration line in nrpe.cfg (or the configuration file in which is added)

Can you run the command in the configuration and post the exit output + the return value of the script?

Comment: I edited the question to include this information.

Comment: What's wrong with the stock check_disk?

Comment: The stock check disk only shows me the Filesystem and only /dev/. This one lists each volume.

Comment: Nrpe should be logging errors via syslog. Anything useful in the log files? That error implies that nrpe knows about the check but isn't getting parsable output back. +1 for trying to run the specified command line on the client as the user that nrpe runs as.

Comment: debug=0. Since this nagios system checks 30 odd servers with many commands I am reluctant to change this setting.

Comment: I changed the output to just OK, WARNING or CRITICAL and it still doesn't work so the problem is not the perfdata format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, this was due to a stupid error. The check script file was installed onto the nagios server instead of the client server. This nagios config is controlled by puppet and some custom checks are installed on the nagios server and some are installed on the client server.

I followed the example of another custom check script which I installed. The only reason that one worked is because somebody had installed it manually in /usr/lib/nagios/plugins on the client server while puppet uselessly installed it on the nagios server as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the full path to your ruby binary at the top of your script.

You can't use `/usr/bin/env ruby` as the interpreter, because NRPE is going to run with no ENV.

This can be simulated by running your script through `env -i`, **as the nagios/nrpe user**:

```
env -i /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_disk_usage.rb
```

Comment: which ruby produced /usr/bin/ruby so should I just remove the env keyword and use #! /usr/bin/ruby?

Comment: Other custom ruby scripts on the same server do use /usr/bin/env ruby

Comment: #!/usr/bin/ruby did not work

Comment: Interesting. Can you add output of a manual test run as the nrpe user?

Comment: The nrpe user is nagios and so the command is documented above in the terminal section.

Comment: I think the solution to this problem is simple. The script was installed in /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/ on the nagios server instead of the nrpe clients. A puppet error.